# Is there a notification when iPod library got changed?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsnotifications, mpmediaitem

I want to cache my custom item picker for music from the iPod library, but I need to know when to refresh it (like after a iTunes sync or when the user purchased a new item through the iTunes store).

Is there any notification I can receive to handle a change of the music library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it myself. The notification is called `MPMediaLibraryDidChangeNotification` and is described in the [MPMediaLibrary Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaLibrary_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html).